# Intel SSE Intrinsics _mm_load_si128 segmentation fault,

Tags: c, sse, simd, memory-alignment, intrinsics

I'm currently working with a 5 x 5 matrix using SSE features.

I'm trying to load x4 128bit integer values to the xmm registers as follows,

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
//===================================== Initialising matrix

int* aligned_matrix;
posix_memalign((void **)&aligned_matrix, 16, sizeof(int) * 25);

for (ssize_t i = 0; i < 25; i++) 
    aligned_matrix[i] = 2; // uniform value of 2 assigned
}
return aligned_matrix;
}

//===================================== then, 

__m128i xmm8, xmm9; 

xmm8 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)(aligned_matrix)); // read 4 from first row

// this line below is where the segmentation fault occurs...
xmm9 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)(aligned_matrix + 5)); // 4 from next row
```

I've got a feeling that this might be related to memory alignment or something but ...I can't pin point where I'm going wrong with this...

I'm using the following,

clang -msse -msse2 -msse4.1

*Note - the reason why I'm adding aligned_matrix + 5 is to read the next 4 elements from the second row of the 5x5 matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second load you need to use `_mm_loadu_si128` because the source data is misaligned. Explanation: an offset of +5 ints from a base address which is 16 byte aligned will no longer be 16 byte aligned.

Comment: why would that matter? All I'm trying to do here is to read the first 4 elements of the first row, then move to the next line and read the next 4 elements. In order to get to the next line I have to "aligned_matrix + 5" as it is 5 x 5 matrix..

Comment: Wow it work! thanks alot. By the way, if I use unaligned load, would there be negative impact on the performance compared to aligned load?

Comment: On older CPUs, yes, but on newer CPUs the penalty is much less, but should still be avoided where possible.